# How do you change CodeMirror settings while the web page is running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I am using CodeMirror to transform my textareas to syntax highlighters. The code looks something like this:

```
<textarea id="editor">
<html>
<body>
<h1>Some Heading</h1>

</body>
</html>
</textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="ln" checked/>
<label for="ln">Toggle Line Numbers</label>
<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor'), {
  mode: "javascript",
  theme: "cobalt",
  lineNumbers: true
});
editor.setSize(1000, 500)
</script>
```

And everything is working well. But I can't change any settings after configuration. I want to know, how do I change, for example, line numbers, to off or on or to any other mode when the web page is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method below to change the CodeMirror settings after its initialization.

```
editor.setOption("OPTION_NAME", YOUR_VALUE); // Structure
editor.setOption("lineNumbers", false);      // Example
```

For more info about the CodeMirror options, see [#setOption](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setOption) and [#event_optionChange](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_optionChange) on the CodeMirror documentation site.

Comment: Is there any way to get values from CodeMirror options? We can set them like that but my problem is I can't get CodeMirror option values.

Comment: Yes, you can get a value of a CodeMirror option by calling `editor.getOption("OPTION_NAME")`. [See more on the documentation.](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getOption)

Comment: Thank you so much, I must have missed this while reading the documentation.